# read data from firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get data from Firestore and save data in `MutableList` and I used the same model in which I stored the data. When I follow the code
They read the size of the array correctly but do not read the data as empty
But the values are not empty in the database.

I need help please:

```
fun getDataQuestions(onComplete: (MutableList<QuestionModel>) -> Unit): ListenerRegistration {
        val id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val doc = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("employerUsers").document(id).collection("Question").whereEqualTo("employeeID",this.EmployeeId )
        return doc.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseExeption ->
            Log.w("firebaseExeption", "" + firebaseExeption)
            Log.i("firebaseExeption", "" + querySnapshot)
            onComplete(querySnapshot!!.toObjects(QuestionModel::class.java))

        }
    }
```

Firestore ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Does this line `Log.w("firebaseExeption", "" + firebaseExeption)` print something?

Comment: @AlexMamo 
It does not print anything

Comment: Is your `onComplete` even triggered?

Comment: @Alex Mamo yes and read array size correctly from firestore

Comment: Where are you trying to log the size of the array?

Comment: Here  querySnapshot!!.toObjects(QuestionModel::class.java)

Comment: I cannot see any log statement there. Can you add it please?